# Are type synonyms with typeclass constraints possible?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Feel free to change the title, I'm just not experienced enough to know what's really going on.

So, I was writing a program loosely based on [this](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~cs8/F2011/notes/11/Sudoku.lhs), and wrote this (as it is in the original)

```
type Row a    = [a]
type Matrix a = [Row a]
```

Nothing special there.
However, I found myself writing a couple of functions with a type like this:

```
Eq a => Row a -> ...
```

So I thought that perhaps I could write this constraint into the type synonym definition, because to my mind it shouldn't be that much more complicated, right? If the compiler can work with this in functions, it should work as a type synonym. There are no partial applications here or anything or some kind of trickery (to my eyes).

So I tried this:

```
type Row a = Eq a => [a]
```

This doesn't work, and the compiler suggested switching on `RankNTypes`. The option made it compile, but the functions still required that I leave the `Eq a =>` in their type declarations. As an aside, if I tried also having a type synonym like `type Matrix a = [Row a]` like before, it results in an error.

So my question(s) are thus:

- Is it possible to have a type synonym with a typeclass constraint in its definition?

  - **If not, why?**
- Is the goal behind this question achievable in some other way?

Comment: You might be interested in the comments for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945348/why-class-constraint-in-type-synonym-needs-rankntypes

Comment: I really tried googling around for this, and I missed this, I swear :P. Then again, I'm not sure if my question is a duplicate or not. It's probably a duplicate of my first question, but not of the second. The question you linked to also doesn't quite have a proper answer. And last, in my case, the code doesn't "compile fine". I'll leave the flagging/deletion up to the community in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Constraints on a type variable can not be part of any Haskell type signature.**

This may seem a bit of a ridiculous statement: "what's `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> a` then?"

The answer is that `a` doesn't really exist, in much the same way there is not really an `x` in the definition `f x = x * log x`. You've sure enough used the `x` symbol in defining that function, but really it was just a local tool used in the lambda-abstraction. There is absolutely no way to access this symbol from the outside, indeed it's not required that the compiler even generates anything *corresponding* to `x` in the machine code – it might just get optimised away.

Indeed, any polymorphic signature can basically be read as a lambda expression accepting a type variable; various writing styles:

```
(==) :: forall a . Eq a => a -> a -> a
(==) :: ∀ a . Eq a => a -> a -> a
(==) :: Λa. {Eq a} -> a -> a -> a
```

This is called [System F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F).

Note that there is not really a "constraint" in this signature, but an extra *argument*: the `Eq`-class dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you want to avoid having constraints in your type synonyms unless it's really necessary. Take the `Data.Set` API from `containers` for example.

Many operations in `Data.Set` require the elements of the set to be instances of `Ord` because `Set` is implemented internally as a binary tree. `member` or `insert` both require `Ord`

```
member :: Ord a => a -> Set a -> Bool
insert :: Ord a => a -> Set a -> Set a
```

However the definition of `Set` doesn't mention `Ord` at all.

This is because some operations on `Set` *dont* require an `Ord` instance, like `size` or `null`.

```
size :: Set a -> Int
null :: Set a -> Bool
```

If the type class constraint was part of the definition of `Set`, these functions would have to include the constraint, even though it's not necessary.

So yes, it is possible to have constraints in type synonyms using `RankNTypes`, but it's generally ill-advised. It's better to write the constraint for the functions that need them instead.

Comment: `Set` is not a type synonym, so it can't serve as an example here.