# Class restriction for type synonyms?

Tags: haskell

I want to do something like:
(In pseudocode; this does not compile)

```
type Num a => Vector2d = (a,a)
```

or possibly

```
type Num a => Vector2d a = (a,a)
```

But I cannot do this.

After reading up I have a feeling that to achieve this I need the `RankNTypes` extension or the `forall` keyword, but I just can't wrap my mind around this...

Can anyone help?

EDIT:
I managed, but rather by "guessing around syntax":
The solution is, indeed with `RankNTypes`:

```
type Vec =  forall a. Num a => (a,a)
```

This works, but with the `RankNTypes` extension

```
type Vec = Num a => (a,a)
```

works equally. What's the difference, and how does a `Num a =>` constraint, which seems quite natural, relate to rank *n* types?

So the question is still open, but I'm looking for an explanation, rather than a solution.

Comment: You may want to read the comments for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945348/why-class-constraint-in-type-synonym-needs-rankntypes). Also this may also be [helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232829/are-type-synonyms-with-typeclass-constraints-possible?lq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`type Vec = forall a. Num a => (a, a)`

is the same thing as

`type Vec = Num a => (a, a)`.

The reason is that every type variable without a corresponding `forall` is implicitly introduced by GHC at the topmost type variable scope, for example:

```
const :: a -> b -> a
const :: forall a b. a -> b -> a -- the same thing
```

For the most part type synonyms are just syntactic convenience, so whenever you see `Vec` in a type signature, you can just put parentheses around its definition and substitute:

```
Vec -> Vec -> Integer
-- equals:
(forall a. Num a => (a, a)) -> (forall a. Num a => (a, a)) -> Integer
```

There is one weird exception, where you can't just blindly substitute in the types. If you have a type synonym like this:

```
type Vec a = Num a => (a, a)
```

then the `Num` constraint floats out to the outermost scope after substitution:

```
vec = (100, 100) :: Vec Integer
-- vec has now type "(Integer, Integer)"
```

and multiple constraints on the same type variable merge:

```
addVec :: Vec a -> Vec a -> Vec a
addVec (a, b) (c, d) = (a + c, b + d)
-- addVec has now effectively type "Num a => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> (a, a)
```

In the above cases the class constraint didn't introduce higher-rankedness, because the constraints were bound to variables in the outer scope. However, when we use the synonym inside data constructors, the constraint turns into an implicit (existential) dictionary:

```
type Foo a = Num a => a 
data Bar a = Bar (Foo a) -- equals "data Bar a = Bar (Num a => a)"
-- requires ExistentialQuantifiaction or GADTs to compile

-- and of course, any data constructor blocks the outwards floating of the constraint:
type Baz = a -> (Foo a, ()) -- requires ImpredicativeTypes.
```

So, to summarize, the behaviour of these kinds of constraints in type synonyms is rather wobbly. We need `RankNTypes` or `Rank2Types` to write them out, but this seems to be more of an implementation artifact than anything else. We could argue that the *syntax* can be used to introduce quantifiers to types, and this sort of justifies the `RankNType` requirement, but we could equally say that it's reasonable that the compiler should detect whether there are fresh quantifiers or not, and proceed accordingly (like it's already being done with the introduced existentials...).

Comment: Köszi, András, but why would those types be rank _n_ | _n_>1 ? Why do I have to enable the `-XRankNTypes` extension for a simple class constraint? How does the type constraint raise the rank of the type (if it does)?

Comment: @ASz: in a nutshell, the rank of a type is the maximum depth at which a `forall` is placed inside function types. `forall a. a -> a` is rank-1, `forall a. (forall b. b -> b) -> a` is rank-2, and so on. It's a complex topic, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031878/what-is-the-purpose-of-rank2types) for an overview. Also, note that although my last "weird" example of type synonyms requires the `RankNTypes` extension, it doesn't actually introduce higher-rankness (it's a bit of bug/quirk, along with the quirks I mentioned in my answer).

Comment: so I had the right feeling, that the constraint does not raise the rank; and it's an implementation quirk, that the syntax extension's implementation is included in a compiler extension, which is named for an unrelated feature?

Comment: As of now, the "Answer" does not answer the actual final question, which you answered here in the comments. If you edit the answer and add the information regarding the relation of the constraint to RankNTypes (ie. that there is none, and it's a naming quirk), I'll happily accept the answer.

Comment: @ASz in the meanwhile I discovered new things, so I included them in the answer.